# Как начать пользоваться StackOverflow на русском, имея учётную запись на оригинальном SO?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-отклонено

В мете уже есть тема, описывающая перенос статистики с ХэшКода.
Там же, в комментариях, есть вопрос на тему привязки статистики с оригинального SO.

Как я понимаю, на данный момент, доминирует мнение, что привязка статистики от оригинального SO не нужна, так как с точки зрения StackExchange это отдельное сообщество. И всё-таки, в то время, как данная позиция выглядит логично для разделения, например, Server Fault и Stack Overflow, сюда она как-то не вписывается. По факту, здесь мы отвечаем на вопросы абсолютно той же тематики.

Единственное препятствие для объединения, которое я на данный момент вижу — то, что в случае добавления связи между аккаунтами, эта связь должна быть двусторонняя. То есть действия пользователя здесь будут влиять на его учётную запись на оригинальном сайте. А, так как ru.stackoverflow.com это молодое сообщество с заведомо более низким качеством модерации, этим могут пользоваться недобросовестные пользователи.

Если принимать во внимание этот факт, нужна ли нам связь с оригинальным SO?

Comment: ru.SO такой же SE сайт как и SO. о какой статистике идёт речь? на всех SE сайтах индифидуальные профили

Comment: @IvanSolntsev это имеет смысл для остальных SE сайтов, которые отличаются по тематике. Тут, возможно, имеет смысл иметь общий профиль для SO и ru.SO.

Comment: Считаю бессмысленным шаринга репутации и аккаунта между enSO и ruSO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. На EN.SO и RU.SO разная политика модерирования.
2. На EN.SO и RU.SO разные пороги для привилегий.
3. На EN.SO и RU.SO разный язык.
4. EN.SO и RU.SO на разных стадиях развития.
5. У EN.SO и RU.SO разные подключенные функции и разнообразные настройки.

Сайты очень разные, несмотря на внешнее сходство. Репутацию на них ну никак нельзя объединять.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы начать пользоваться используя SO учётную запись, достаточно авторизоваться через SE учетную запись.

Касательно дополнительной использования одной учетной записи между ru.SO и SO: это не нужно. Локализованные SO сайты используют отдельные учётные записи, например на https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all