# Часто задаваемые вопросы о Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: поддержка, faq, stackoverflow, stackexchange

## Руководство по Stack Overflow на русском от Сообщества

Если вы искали ответ на свой вопрос, но не нашли его в этом списке и в поиске, [задайте новый вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Пожалуйста, не задавайте вопросы в комментариях или ответе к этому.

Если вы хотите добавить какую–либо ссылку в документ, оставьте комментарий или предложите правку. Прежде чем редактировать документ, обязательно прочитайте [руководство по редактированию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/984/181472).

Это руководство поддерживается силами сообщества StackOverflow на русском языке.

### Вопросы

- [Как правильно использовать модель вопросов и ответов Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/643/)
- [Что делать если у меня возник вопрос который уже был задан, но ответ на него отсутствует?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/428/)
- [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику stackoverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/)
- [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/)
- [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/)

### Ответы

- [Стоит ли переводить вопросы и ответы с англоязычного SO?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/70/)

### Различные действия с вопросами и ответами

- [Автоматическое удаление заброшенных вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/)
- [Получает ли автор вопроса уведомление при изменении ответа?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/583/)
- [Что делать: ответ не принят, пользователя нет?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1299/)
- [Может ли модератор принять ответ на вопрос за автора?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/167/)

### Комментарии

- [Комментарий или ответ?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419/)
- [Перенос информации из комментариев в ответ — удалять ли комментарии?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/189/)
- [Список шаблонных комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1222/)
- [Как использовать шаблонные комментарии?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1225/)

### Редактирование и форматирование

- [Коллективная правка содержимого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/220/)
- [Коллективная правка — залог качественного содержимого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420/)
- [Приветствия, подписи, мольбы, благодарности, лирические отступления, истории из жизни](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/93/)
- [Как добавить таблицу в текст вопроса на StackOverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/194/)
- [Имеет ли смысл убирать слово-метку из заголовка вопроса?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/607/)
- [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/)
- [Как следует писать кавычки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/493/)
- [Какие HTML теги можно использовать на сайтах Stack Exchange?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5776)

### Использование меток

**Наменования меток**

- [Правила наименования меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251/)
- [Язык меток: русский или английский (а также синонимы)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/)
- [Метки: множественное или единственное число?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327/)

**Описания и краткие описания меток**

- Раздел справки: [Что должно содержать краткое описание метки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)
- [Важность качественного описания меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/188/)
- [Как правильно составлять описание метки (tag wiki)? Что туда включать?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/527/)
- [Копирование статей из Википедии в описания меток — это плохо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/138/)

### Репутация и голосование

- [В чем значение голосов «за» и «против»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1036/)

### Знаки

- [Может ли быть присвоен знак «Страж» если для проверок недостаточно репутации?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423/)

### Модерация и участие в ней

- [Как и какие вопросы следует закрывать? В каких случаях?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271/)
- [Как бороться с некачественными вопросами?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418/)
- [Что делать с вопросами в стиле "скажите что почитать"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/)
- [Что за snippets с "Выполнить код"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381/)
- [Что делать, если принятый ответ — ошибочный или вредоносный?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/961/)
- [Автоматический минус ответу при его правке из "Сообщения плохого качества"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/689/)
- [Что делать с рекламой в сообщениях?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337/)

### Этикет

- [Что делать, если вопрос вызывает злость?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/535/)
- [Какое обращение следует использовать: Вы / вы / ты?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/489/)

### Вклад в развитие StackOverflow на русском языке

- [Долгосрочные цели для сообщества StackOverflow на русском языке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/955/)
- [Какие изменения необходимы Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/594/)

**Аттестация сайта**

- [Статистика отвеченных вопросов и актуальные задачи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1339/181472)
- [Какие изменения в привилегиях произойдут после аттестации сайта?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1216/181472)
- [Как считается статистика отвечаемости вопросов на Area 51?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/807/181472)

**Локализация сайта**

- [Коллективный перевод сайта сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/)
- [Кому сообщить об орфографических ошибках в интерфейсе ru.stackoverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/)
- [Каким образом принимать решения о выборе правильного варианта перевода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/494/)
- [Как редактировать справку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/91/)
- [Как следует писать кавычки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/493/)

### Учетные записи, регистрация и миграция

- [Как начать пользоваться Stack Overflow на русском, имея учётную запись на ХэшКоде?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/24/)
- [Как начать пользоваться StackOverflow на русском, имея учётную запись на оригинальном SO?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/119/)
- [Подписка на уведомления по почте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/442/)

### Реклама

- [Где разместить рекламу на StackOverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/951/)

### Прочие вопросы

- [Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/173/)

### Внешние ссылки

- Аналогичный документ на английском языке: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/)
- Аналогичный документ на Мете StackOverflow на португальском: [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/30162)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Руководство для редакторов

Для обсуждения содержания, правил, критериев и целей предлагаю использовать [чат по технической документации](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26118/technical-writing).

## 1. Что еще добавить?

Есть несколько источников наполнения FAQ:

1. Реальные задаваемые вопросы.
2. Вопросы по технической стороне, которые пока что не заданы, но которые очевидно будут когда-нибудь заданы. Многие из них можно перевести с англоязычной Меты.

- Как считается реферальная статистика для знаков группы [Диктор](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer)?

3. Вопросы, которые разобраны на англоязычной Мете и которые касаются правил сообщества. Их нельзя просто перевести (т.к. мы не копируем правила без адаптации), их нужно будет когда-нибудь задать и обсудить.

## 2. Критерии добавления

Подходят:

- Любые вопросы, отмеченные меткой [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).
- Вопросы, ответы к которым объясняют механизмы работы StackExchange, например репутацию, знаки, форматирование или модерацию.

Не подходят:

- Любые вопросы с метками [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-proposal](/questions/tagged/feature-proposal).

## 3. Ссылки

#### 3.1. Внутренние ссылки

Все ссылки на внутренние вопросы ru.meta.stackoverflow.

**Формат:**

```html
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12345/ <!-- Заголовок оригинального вопроса -->
```

Закомментированный текст нужен для удобства редакторов. Когда вопросов будет много, мы не запутаемся.

#### 3.2. Внешние ссылки

Только в разделе «Внешние ссылки». Ссылки на другие сайты сети кроме StackOverflow на русском языке считаются внешними.

**Формат:**

```html
[Заголовок оригинального вопроса](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12345/)
```

#### 3.3. Любые ссылки на страницы внутри сети Stack Exchange:

- Используется ссылка, получаемая при нажатии на кнопку «поделиться» под вопросом.
  Это самый лаконичный вариант, не содержащий текста вопроса (кириллица все равно разворачивается в нечитаемую кашу).
- Реферальную часть (последнее число) нужно убрать.
- Ссылка дается на вопрос, а не ответ.

## 4. Эволюция этого документа (руководства для редакторов).

Разумеется, это черновой вариант правил и его предстоит совершенствовать. Особенно в части критериев. Предлагаю вести обсуждение в чате или созданием вопросов на Мете по ключевым пунктам.