# Какие изменения в привилегиях произойдут после аттестации сайта?

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange, аттестация

близится момент перехода нашего сайта из состояния «бета» в «полноценный» сайт сети stackexchange.

какие изменения в привилегиях при этом произойдут?

Comment: хотя бы примерная дата перехода из беты уже известна?

Comment: @PashaPash, следите за [новостями](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/956/178576).

Comment: я слежу, и по вашей ссылке даже есть мои комменты. но я так и не увидел **официального** подтверждения, что 85% - это необходимое и **достаточное** условие для выхода из беты. к тому же даты, хоть и примерной, по ссылке нет. есть только предполагаемая дата от Nick Volynkin. с такой же достоверностью я могу написать "завтра!"

Comment: @PashaPash, насколько я понимаю, окончательное решение остаётся, конечно, за руководством stackexchange. а принимать оно его будет, руководствуясь, в частности, [данными с area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian), ссылка на которые и приведена в ответе, на который я указал.

Comment: @PashaPash: там есть набор из критериев, качество вопросов и ответов — только один из них. Официального подтверждения, как вы верно заметили, не было. Кстати, я не хотел бы как-то искусственно торопить этот процесс.

Comment: @PashaPash: дата от меня — даже не столько предполагаемая, сколько предлагаемая. Я предлагаю разобрать детально все критерии выхода из Беты и выполнить их до конца года. С момента публикации того вопроса прошел месяц, пора бы дальше прояснять ситуацию. Про критерии аттестации есть тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta

Comment: @NickVolynkin я уже написал выше - хотелось бы **официального** подтверждения что, что показатели и пороги на area51 - это действительно критерии выхода из беты. По ссылке на whats-beta нет **ничего** конкретного про критерии аттестации. Там даже не упоминается процент отвеченных вопросов. Есть только ссылка в английский блог, где тоже не упоминается процент отвеченных вопросов. tldr - хотелось бы сообщения от Николаса "да, вот наберем 85% - и сразу релиз". а не гадания. Тем более что предположение о 85% подразумевает кучу рутины по разгребанию старых никому не нужных вопросов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin под критерием я имею ввиду именно необходимое и достаточное условие. а не какие-то "оценки" и общие фразы "столько, сколько требуется для достижения критической массы" со ссылками вникуда.

Comment: Добавил этот вопрос в [Часто задаваемые вопросы о StackOverflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

увидеть отличия можно, сравнивая два списка: [ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) и [stackoverflow.com/help/privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). ниже приведен «сборный» список, в котором отражено изменение в количестве баллов за ту или иную привилегию.

изменения коснутся только «дорогостоящих» привилегий и, в целом, количество баллов увеличится в некоторой нелинейной прогрессии.

«выпадают» из прогрессии лишь две привилегии, отмеченные жирным шрифтом.

---

- [access to site analytics](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)

  5,000 → 25,000
- [trusted user](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)
  Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges

  4,000 → 20,000
- [защищенные вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)
  Отмечать вопросы как защищенные

  3,500 → 15,000
- [Инструменты модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)
  Доступ к статистике, удалению вопросов и очереди проверок

  2,000 → 10,000
- [Принятие описания меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)
  Принятие описания меток других участников

  1,500 → 5,000
- [Создание синонимов меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)
  Решайте, какие метки имеют схожее значение

  1,250 → 2,500
- [правка вопросов и ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)
  Правка любых вопросов и ответов минуя проверку

  1,000 → 2,000
- [Создавать чат-витрину](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms)
  Создавайте чаты, с ограничением на участие

  1,000 → 1,000
- [Постоянный пользователь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)
  Просмотр голосов, улучшеный аватар

  750 → 1,000
- [Голос за закрытие или повторное открытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)
  Помощь в решении о закрытии вопросов

  **500 → 3,000**
- [Очередь проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)
  Очередь запоздалых ответов и первых сообщений

  350 → 500
- [Видеть голоса за закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)
  Просмотр голосов за закрытие ваших вопросов

  250 → 250
- [Создание новых меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
  Добавляйте новые метки на сайт

  **150 → 1,500**
- [Голосовать против](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)
  Показывайте, когда вопрос или ответ не несет пользы

  125 → 125
- [Редактировать общие сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)
  Объединяйтесь для улучшения общих сообщений

  100 → 100
- [Создание чатов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)
  Создание новых чатов

  100 → 100
- [Начинать конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)
  Предложите награду за ответ на вопрос

  75 → 75
- [Повсеместное комментирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)
  Оставляйте комментарии к сообщениям других участников

  50 → 50
- [Общение в чатах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)
  Общение в различных чатах

  20 → 20
- [flag posts](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
  Bring content to the attention of the community via flags

  15 → 15
- [Голосовать за](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)
  Объявить, что вопрос или ответ полезен

  15 → 15
- [Снять ограничения новичка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)
  Снять ограничения действующие для новичков

  10 → 10
- [create wiki posts](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)
  Create answers that can be easily edited by most users

  10 → 10
- [Участвовать на Мете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
  Обсуждение работы форума, модераторов и публикация отзывов

  5 → 5
- [Задавать и отвечать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts)
  Задавать вопросы или делиться знаниями в ответах

  1 → 1

---

и, особняком, про рекламу, которая на «бете» не показывается (и для которой нет даже соотвествующей странички на `ru.stackoverflow.com`):

- [reduce ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)
  Some ads are now automatically disabled

  200

Comment: Ну вот, а вы говорили, что язык не подвешен. Хороший обзор же.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это лишь перечисление фактов. тут «язык» не нужен. а для **правильной** инструкции — очень даже нужен.

Comment: меня этой весной специально учили писать технические инструкции. Может, выложить тут конспект? Впрочем, ничего революционного там нет.

Comment: А что будет с теми, кто уже имеет эти привилегии, но по новой шкале имеет недостаточный уровень?

Comment: @Qwertiy, насколько я понимаю, «будут разжалованы». но, на всякий случай, задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Э​​х​​​ ​​:​​​(

Comment: @alexanderbarakin черт, я не смогу защищать вопросы!

Comment: @Qwertiy: да, точно будут. Это повод не слишком торопить аттестацию )

Comment: @PashaPash: да почти никто не сможет ))

Comment: @PashaPash да ладно "защита вопросов" - тут вот возможность голосовать за закрытие вопросов может уплыть из рук...

Answer (score 10):

## Требования каких привилегий изменятся?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все остальные привилегии будут даваться на том же уровне репутации.

> [Посмотреть на эту таблицу в Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14JKT9QW8U1yyvz7dZXT_dz24x9c3hkmEh1IPkAgK6xg/edit?usp=sharing)

## Произойдет пересчёт привилегий

Что важно понимать: при аттестации сайта произойдет пересчёт привилегий. Почти для всех участников уровень привилегий на сайте снизится.

Это одна из тех причин, почему нужно стимулировать голосование за *хорошие* вопросы и ответы. Нам нужны опытные и активные участники, имеющие 3,000 репутации. Даже после аттестации сайта они сохранят возможность закрывать вопросы, таким образом, осуществляя существенную часть модерации сайта.

Comment: выходит, что [эта цель](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/956/178576) — вредна?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: настолько же, насколько ребенку вредно взрослеть, жить самостоятельно и обеспечивать себя. Думаю, что аттестация не произойдёт раньше, чем мы будем к ней готовы. Искусственно торопить её не стоит, но цель по расчистке неотвеченных вопросов я не считаю искусственной. Это большой труд, который 1) уточняет тематику сайта 2) дает большому количеству участников опыт модерации 3) сплачивает сообщество вокруг общей цели. Думаю, нам даже в каком-то смысле повезло, что у нас есть такое наследие вопросов — как хороших, так и не очень.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: более того, я считаю, что повышение планки привилегий — это очень хорошо. Такие вещи, как закрытие вопросов и создание меток, сейчас неоправданно легко достаются. Пока у нас есть 15000 неразобранных вопросов — хорошо, что закрывать могут менее опытные участники. Когда мы эту кучу разберем — тогда повышение планки будет уместно и своевременно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: (не получается сегодня быть лаконичным) То есть цель — не вредна, но вредно достигать её необдуманно и механически (там jfs писал об этом).