# Как правильно поступить с ошибочной меткой (с опечаткой)?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

Сегодня был задан вопрос с меткой "javaskript". Метку в вопросе я поправил, в описании к метке "javaskript" указал что метка ошибочная и не надо ее использовать, потому что возможности удаления не нашел. Сейчас "javaskript" живет с моим описанием, но мне кажется что такой метки вообще не должно быть. В связи с этим вопрос: стоит ли делать для таких новых меток с ошибками описания или же достаточно поправить метку в вопросе и она исчезнет?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Чтобы удалить метку, достаточно удалить её из всех вопросов. В течение суток она прекратит своё существование — удалится вся статистика, описания и история изменений этих описаний.

После этого метку, конечно, можно будет создать заново. Не думаю, что это существенная проблема — после аттестации [порог для создания меток существенно поднимется](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1216/181472) и каждый желающий не сможет создавать ошибочные метки.

В общем, вы все правильно сделали.

Comment: Ну и славно. Думал что оно сразу исчезнет, но теперь все понятно.