# Нам не нужна [проблема]

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

С меткой [проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0) связано 32 вопроса. Никакой информации она не несет и в классификацию вопросов ничего не привносит. Если метку оставить, её можно ставить любому вопросу, поскольку любой вопрос по сути - проблема.

Может, стоит удалить эту метку?

Comment: Да, это мета-метка, нужно от нее избавляться.

Comment: Я так понимаю, это "фас". Пошел вытирать :) 
@Nofate Кстати как-то можно метки добавлять в какой-либо "стоп-лист" или написать в её описание "НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ" как в метке "скрипт"?

Comment: Стоп-листов нет, механизма массового удаления- тоже. Есть только костыль с "НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ". Но в данном случае проще поправить 32 вопроса и неиспользованная метка самоудалится через некоторое время. Правда, вы рискуете навлечь на себя недовольство блюстителей чистой главной страницы, вываливая на нее кучу старья. )

Comment: Спасибо, что предупредили. Буду чистить по-немногу. Может еще кто-то подтянется.

Comment: Во, теперь отличное название! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Метка почти бесполезна — кроме того, что она сигнализирует: **проблема есть в постановке вопроса**. Почти наверняка вопрос нуждается в правке, хотя бы в новых нормальных метках.

Поэтому нужно с каждого вопроса эту метку удалить, а вместо нее поставить новые, адекватные. [Например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/443523/revisions): [проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0), [ввод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4), [программа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0) >> [intellij-idea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea), [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)

После того, как метка будет удалена со всех вопросов, наш garbage collector полностью ее уничтожит (Подробнее: [Как правильно поступить с ошибочной меткой (с опечаткой)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/181472))

Не бойтесь блюстителей чистоты главной страницы, у вас есть сторонники. =)

Comment: *Не бойтесь блюстителей чистоты главной страницы, у вас есть сторонники* — гхм… сторонники в борьбе с блюстителями чистоты главной страницы?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin читайте комментарий Nofate к вопросу. Это я к тому, что старые вопросы стоит редактировать, даже если при этом они все появляются в топе.

Answer (score 1):

На сегодня с [`проблемой`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0) покончено.

Comment: А какой смысл [удалять одну бесполезную метку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/184668), чтобы назначить другую, полезность которой тоже сомнительна?

Comment: Мне кажется другая метка наполнена смыслом.