# Репутация необходимая для достижения определённых привилегий

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, привилегии

Репутация необходимая для получения определённых [привилегий на ru SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) разительно порой отличается от репутации необходимой для получения определённых [привилегий на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Можно узнать, из каких соображений это сделано и почему именно такие цифры? Я понимаю, что, вероятно, частично это вызвано тем, что на ru SO слишком мало пользователей и, следовательно, вопросов намного меньше, по сему сложно набрать требуемую репутацию. Но были ли ещё какие-то критерии?

Во-первых, меня интересует вопрос сам по себе.

Во-вторых, из этого вопроса вытекает кое-какой, хм, нюанс. Привилегии - это как стимул, не большой, но всё же. Когда пользователь на ru SO достигает 5к репутации, то в плане привилегий у него больше нет новой цели, что заставляет немного фрустрировать =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это стандартные уровни репутации для сайта Stack Exchange в бета-стадии. Когда сайт пройдет аттестацию, все требования повысятся в среднем в пять раз, а привилегии будут пересчитаны. То есть, у большинства участников станет меньше доступных привилегий.

[Какие изменения в привилегиях произойдут после аттестации сайта?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1216/181472)

Comment: Тогда при завершении беты будет проблема с тем, что для достижения этих привилегий потребуется в разы больше времени нежели на en SO в силу того, что тут аудитория меньше.

Comment: @Suvitruf меня это не пугает. )

Comment: Мы с вами, как минимум, лишимся инструментов модератора. Для их получения надо будет удвоить нашу текущую репутацию.

Comment: @Suvitruf ну вот будет стимул. Закрывать и удалять все равно сможем. )

Comment: @Suvitruf а вообще, по моему опыту, самый хороший инструмент модерации это Мета. Возможность участвовать в жизни сообщества останется у всех.

Comment: На мете активность совсем не ахти =/

Comment: @Suvitruf на пост про отставку модератора реакция была очень бурная.

Comment: Это скорее исключение (:

Comment: Да и основная группа активных участников наверняка читает каждый пост. Мысли и идеи можно донести.

Comment: @Suvitruf вы-то что думаете по этому вопросу?

Comment: В контексте "активных юзеров" меня печалит то, что их число в целом постоянно. Новых активных юзеров слишком мало появляется =/