# Почему очередь на закрытие забита нормальными вопросами?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок

210 вопросов из очереди на закрытие были обработаны следующим образом:

```
 => 33
Закрыть: 1 => 30
Закрыть: 1, Оставить открытым: 1 => 1
Закрыть: 1, Оставить открытым: 3 => 7
Закрыть: 1, Правка: 1 => 2
Закрыть: 2 => 8
Закрыть: 2, Оставить открытым: 1 => 1
Закрыть: 2, Оставить открытым: 2 => 4
Закрыть: 2, Оставить открытым: 3 => 6
Закрыть: 2, Правка: 1 => 1
Закрыть: 3 => 20
Закрыть: 3, Оставить открытым: 1 => 3
Закрыть: 3, Оставить открытым: 2 => 1
Закрыть: 3, Оставить открытым: 3 => 1
Закрыть: 4 => 11
Закрыть: 4, Оставить открытым: 1 => 19
Закрыть: 4, Оставить открытым: 2 => 4
Закрыть: 4, Оставить открытым: 3 => 1
Закрыть: 5 => 12
Закрыть: 5, Оставить открытым: 1 => 7
Закрыть: 5, Оставить открытым: 2 => 5
Оставить открытым: 1 => 13
Оставить открытым: 1, Правка: 1 => 3
Оставить открытым: 2 => 1
Оставить открытым: 3 => 15
Правка: 1 => 1
```

Видно, что число вопросов без голосов за закрытие более 18%. 
Число вопросов с 3 голосами "Оставить открытым" около 17%, а в некоторых проверках были голоса модераторов.
Предположительно доля незакрытых вопросов может приближаться к 25%.

Встречаются в очереди и очевидно хорошие вопросы, например:

- [В чем польза yield?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505018/178988)
  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/70194
- [Массив из с++ в c# - C++/CLI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506359/178988)
  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/70426
- [Дозапись файла новыми данными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507033/178988)
  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/70905

На самом деле больше, но это надо искать.

На мой взгляд, что-то не так с наполнением очереди.
Может быть стоит кому-нибудь ограничить возможность помещать в неё сообщения?

---

Скрипт подсчёта для хрома:

```
var http = Object.create(null), res = Object.create(null), used = Object.create(null), total = 0;

function process(id) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("Processing: " + id);
    fetch("/review/close/" + id).then(resp => { 
      http[resp.status] = ~~http[resp.status] + 1;

      if (resp.status === 200) {
        fetch("/review/next-task/" + id, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
          body: "taskTypeId=2&fkey=" + StackExchange.options.user.fkey
        }).then(
          resp => {
            if (resp.status === 200) {
              resp.json().then(data => {
                var a = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(data.content, "text/html").querySelector("a[href^='/questions/']");

                if (!a) {
                  console.error(id);
                  resolve();
                  return;
                }

                var qid = +a.getAttribute('href').match(/\d+/)[0];

                if (!used[qid]) {
                  used[qid] = 1;
                  var cur = Object.create(null);

                  for(var elem of Array.from((new DOMParser).parseFromString(data.instructions, "text/html").querySelectorAll(".review-results b"))) {
                    var status = elem.textContent;
                    cur[status] = ~~cur[status] + 1;
                  }

                  cur = Object.keys(cur).sort().map(status => status + ": " + cur[status]).join(", ");
                  res[cur] = ~~res[cur] + 1;
                  ++total;
                } else {
                  ++used[qid];
                }

                resolve();
              });
            } else {
              console.error(resp.status);
              resolve();
            }
          },
          err => {
            console.error(err);
            resolve();
          }
        );
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    },
    err => {
      console.error(err);
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

function go(l, r) {
  process(l).then(nothing => {
    if (++l <= r) {
      go(l, r);
    } else {
      console.log("Results:");
      console.log(total);
      console.log(Object.keys(res).sort().map(r => r + " => " + res[r]).join("\n"));
      console.log(http);
      console.log(used);
    }
  });
}

go(69000, 70555)
```

Были проверены вопросы с id проверок в диапазоне 69000 - 70555, при условии, что проверка принадлежит очереди на закрытие и удалось распарсить id вопроса (зря я это условие прописал, проверка сама однозначна), а именно:

> 58927, 128497, 174571, 285327, 297910, 426560, 427039, 464281, 483795, 488020, 488416, 490460, 491518, 491831, 493803, 494695, 495095, 495105, 495390, 495530, 496079, 497029, 497093, 497489, 498529, 500535, 500989, 501367, 501436, 502685, 503083, 504000, 504174, 504184, 504189, 504193, 504217, 504220, 504221, 504261, 504282, 504284, 504289, 504303, 504328, 504336, 504338, 504343, 504356, 504363, 504369, 504402, 504433, 504461, 504470, 504484, 504545, 504548, 504551, 504561, 504590, 504601, 504623, 504651, 504669, 504677, 504681, 504694, 504706, 504711, 504739, 504741, 504748, 504753, 504760, 504762, 504769, 504771, 504805, 504806, 504812, 504828, 504834, 504851, 504856, 504863, 504891, 504911, 504912, 504937, 504971, 504975, 504997, 505007, 505018, 505026, 505033, 505045, 505094, 505095, 505096, 505107, 505109, 505113, 505124, 505132, 505137, 505138, 505169, 505191, 505208, 505213, 505224, 505229, 505233, 505249, 505269, 505298, 505305, 505312, 505332, 505357, 505372, 505375, 505397, 505402, 505424, 505453, 505468, 505490, 505491, 505508, 505517, 505520, 505567, 505568, 505569, 505570, 505608, 505618, 505629, 505636, 505654, 505658, 505670, 505689, 505700, 505703, 505708, 505725, 505740, 505747, 505770, 505771, 505773, 505774, 505793, 505815, 505819, 505824, 505836, 505840, 505879, 505902, 505918, 505958, 505966, 505968, 505969, 505988, 505989, 506007, 506008, 506016, 506020, 506034, 506035, 506039, 506057, 506058, 506122, 506131, 506188, 506190, 506198, 506207, 506226, 506298, 506306, 506309, 506323, 506333, 506344, 506359, 506366, 506374, 506379, 506397, 506413, 506414, 506426, 506430, 506439, 506457, 506459, 506463, 506485, 506513, 506517, 506525

Comment: В чем вопрос-то? Сообществу не нравится вопрос - его кидают в очередь.  Кто-то может попытаться закрыть хороший вопрос, Кто-то может попытаться спасти плохой.

Comment: @Nofate, просто их слишком много в очереди. Можно же проверить, а вдруг это кто-то один накидывает туда хорошие вопросы?

Comment: Караул! Диверсанты завелись! Срочно надо СМЕРШ организовывать)

Answer (score 13):

Очередь вопросов подлежащих закрытию -- это всего лишь механизм. Настоящая проблема, если она и есть, кроется в поведении сообщества. На мой взгляд, ситуация сводится к тому, что сообщество стало строже относится к качеству вопросов. Вместе с тем, кроме очевидно плохих вопросов в очередь попадают и хорошие.

Итак, почему отношение сообщества к качеству вопросов могло измениться:

1. Стало слишком много плохих вопросов от новичков, сообщество слишком яро взялось за чистку рядов и немного перестаралось.
2. В сообщество пришло достаточно много новичков, которые либо не понимают общепринятых критериев качества либо просто не хотят им следовать.
3. Активные участники сообщества стали хуже относится к вопросам "на грани". (Не буду скрывать, это касается меня лично.)
4. Относительный объем очереди на закрытие осталось тем же, что и раньше, но абсолютное число вопросов в очереди выросло из-за роста популярности ru.SO. Количество проверяющих не изменилось, в итоге очередь переполнена.

Ни одна из этих причин не лечится и *не должна лечиться* техническими методами. Это чисто социальная проблема - сообщество ведет себя не так, как того хочет **@Qwertiy**. (Более того, критерии качества у каждого из участников разные и то, что кажется участнику **@Qwertiy** приличными вопросами может не являться таковым по мнению сообщества.)

В целом, я не вижу в ситуации ничего такого, что могло бы вызывать панику.

Решение проблемы очень простое, нужно проводить разъяснительную работу в рядах сообщества, показывая на своем примере что хорошо, а что плохо. Строго следовать правилам и решениям меты и мотивировать остальных делать то же.

Кроме того, ситуации, когда откровенно плохой вопрос остается только потому, что он нравится одному из активных участников (не буду показывать пальцем) должны быть **исключительными**, а не являться правилом. Серьезно, такое поведение подрывает авторитет правил и принятых решений.

Все изложенное выше является моим субъективным мнением и не претендует на достоверность.

Answer (score 8):

> Почему очередь на закрытие забита нормальными вопросами?

вероятно, примерно по той же причине, по которой она **вообще** забита вопросами, требующими проверки: слишком мало желающих потратить на это время, проголосовать за то, чтобы либо закрыть вопрос, либо оставить его открытым.

а вызвано такое «оскудение» вполне объективной причиной: после завершения бета-стадии увеличился порог репутации, необходимой для голосования в этой очереди, [с 500 до 3000 баллов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1217/178576).

Answer (score 5):

### Вы неправильно понимаете цель очереди

Потому что это очередь **на проверку** на закрытие. Нет ничего удивительного, что в очередь могут попадать и плохие и хорошие вопросы - часть из них тревоги, часть чужие голоса за закрытие, часть автоопределение системой. Задача эти вопросы проверить и принять по ним решение.

Так же не забывайте:

- вопрос сначала набирает голоса за закрытие (кстати, топикстартер видит цифру в скобках?)
- "закрытый" вопрос сначала становится "требующим правки" - это стимул автору улучшить его
- потом вопрос становится закрытым - на него не принимаются ответы, но его по прежнему можно редактировать
- и только потом, при отсутствии ответов отправляется на удаление

Весь этот механизм, длиной в два дня (емнип) - направлен на проверку и улучшение качества вопросов.

Comment: Топикстартер видит цифру в скобках только с получением 250 баллов репутации и привилегии [Видеть голоса за закрытие](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).