# Зачем нужны тревоги "необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса", если они так часто отклоняются?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

В последнее время было отклонено несколько моих тревог, которые я считаю адекватными. При поднятии этих тревог, я руководствовался вот этим пояснением:

> Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

- [Не хватает памяти [php]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520234) (-5)
  Вопросу бы не помешало уточнение и развернутое описание, тогда бы вопрос мог набрать больше плюсов.
- [Дан алгоритм (формула), сделайте на любом языке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515861) (-15)
  Автор не потрудился написать в чем у него возникли затруднения, что он хотел бы получить (код, разжевать алгоритм, что-то еще?), он не привел кода. Один в один как написано в описании тревоги.
- [Найти все числа от 2 до n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/42097) (-1)
  Опять, автор не потрудился написать в чем у него возникли затруднения, что он хотел бы получить (код, разжевать алгоритм, что-то еще?), он не привел кода. Один в один как написано в описании тревоги.
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519478 (Можно ли использовать BIO_puts, BIO_read несколько раз без переподключения? вопрос удален)
  Насколько помню, вопрос был похож на первый - минимум описания проблемы.
- [Как сохранить массив в базу данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518867) (+1)
  Слишком широкий вопрос, не указано в чем затруднение, что за массив и т.д.

Неужели эти вопросы развернутые, с добротным описанием проблемы с которой столкнулся автор, описанием как ее воспроизвести, желаемым результатом и т.д. С примерами кода/конфигов/данными?

Answer (score 9):

> Необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса

Это не совсем тревоги. Это некая обёртка над закрытием для пользователей с недостаточной репутацией. Если репутации достаточно, то этот пункт просто перекидывает на диалог Закрыть. Если же репутации недостаточно, вопрос без голосов за закрытие отправляется в очередь проверок на закрытие. Там за него голосуют как посчитают нужным.

Обрати внимание на [Почему очередь на закрытие забита нормальными вопросами?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2782/178988) - многие вопросы остаются открытыми после прохождение через очередь.

---

Теперь по вопросам.

> [Не хватает памяти [php]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520234) (-5)
>   Вопросу бы не помешало уточнение и развернутое описание, тогда бы вопрос мог набрать больше плюсов.

Не знаю, что там можно уточнить. Выложить весь код и все настройки? Вряд ли.
К тому же, там хорошие ответы - похоже, вопрос поняли и так.

> [Дан алгоритм (формула), сделайте на любом языке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515861) (-15)
>   Автор не потрудился написать в чем у него возникли затруднения, что он хотел бы получить (код, разжевать алгоритм, что-то еще?), он не привел кода. Один в один как написано в описании тревоги.

Когда была поставлена тревога? Возможно, к тому времени вопрос уже превратили в соревнование и уточнять было поздно? По нему есть почти отдельная тема на мете: [Узаконим гольф?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84?cb=1)

> [Найти все числа от 2 до n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/42097) (-1)
>   Опять, автор не потрудился написать в чем у него возникли затруднения, что он хотел бы получить (код, разжевать алгоритм, что-то еще?), он не привел кода. Один в один как написано в описании тревоги.

Вопрос задан в 2011 году, последнее появление автора на сайте в 2014. Просить автора о чём-то поздно. При этом вопрос предельно понятен.

> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519478 (Можно ли использовать BIO_puts, BIO_read несколько раз без переподключения? вопрос удален)
>   Насколько помню, вопрос был похож на первый - минимум описания проблемы.

Не могу оценить. В любом случае, вопрос удалён автором с комментарием: "Не туда запостил)".

> [Как сохранить массив в базу данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518867) (+1)
>   Слишком широкий вопрос, не указано в чем затруднение, что за массив и т.д.

Ответ дан и принят. Лично моя позиция, что закрывать вопросы как неясные, если у них уже есть нормальный принятый ответ, поздно. Возможно, кто-то с ней согласен :)
Кстати, один голос за закрытие на этом вопросе всё-таки висит.

Comment: Проверь первый абзац плиз, тревога != "голос за закрытие", поэтому она и называется тревогой.

Comment: @KromStern, после того, как наберёшь нужную репутацию, пункт "тревога -> должен быть закрыт" ведёт на диалог голоса за закрытия, с переключением на соответствующий счётчик лимитов. Для тех, кто ещё не набрал достаточно репутации, она отличается  тем, что голос не выставляется, а вопрос отправляется в очередь на проверку. Хотя да, первое предложение я как-то криво сформулировал. Попробую улучшитью

Answer (score 9):

Для меня SO в большей мере база знаний, а не форум помощи новичкам.

Ведь важен не только ответ, но и хорошо  сформулированный вопрос. Такой вопрос, который можно найти гуглом. Я уже много лет пользуюсь английским SO и мне чрезвычайно нравится то, что введя ключевые слова проблемы в гугле, в первых строках всегда есть 2-3 результата с SO. Причем в вопросе будет сформулирована достаточно конкретная ситуация, которую можно сравнить со своей проблемой и решения будут отвечать именно этой ситуации, а не гадать на кофейной гуще.

Что для этого нужно? - Повышать качество вопросов! А как его можно повысить?

- Правками, улучшая формулировки (переименовать "Проблема с N" в "Делаю А, получается В, а как сделать С?")
- Добавлением подробностей, которые помогут вопросу быть найденным (заменяя "решите эту формулу с картинки", на "как решаются уравнения типа А методом В")
- Поднятием разнообразных тревог (*.. тут много текста о том что все и так знают - зачем нужны тревоги и закрытия вопросов..*)
- Отметкой "нуждается в правке". Во многих случаях, стимулирование сформулировать вопрос, проблему и желаемый результат, уже приводит к решению.
- Нужно поддерживать порядок и показывать, что новые вопросы нуждающиеся в улучшении, действительно должны быть улучшены авторами. (*Собственно причина возникновения этого вопроса на Мете*).

Хотелось бы, чтобы русский SO:

- поддерживал культуру задавания хороших вопросов
- не превращался в форум, где нет побуждений улучшать вопросы, где решаются только сиюминутные проблемы сиюминутных людей
- не был базой знаний, где плохой вопрос заданный 4 года назад не может быть закрыт из-за того что "он же получил ответ" (*..тут текст про то что все и так знают, что закрытие != удаление, и что отредактированный вопрос можно переоткрыть..*)
- не был местом, где одни и те же проблемы возникают раз в 2 месяца и их нельзя объединить как дубликаты, потому что их даже нельзя толком найти. "но тут же спрашивают как решить x+y, а там как решить y+x"
- не был домом для партии "давайте спасем все вопросы от закрытия: вот инструкция как не дать закрыть вопрос используя лазейки SO"
- а стал домом для партии "[мы создаем свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour): вот инструкция как приводить вопросы в порядок"