# Как ускорить обработку очереди «за закрытие»?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, очередь-проверок

Все опытные пользователи ru.so в курсе, что среди [всех очередей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) проверок очередь «[за закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)» — самая «долгоиграющая». В данный момент в ней «висит» 70 вопросов, ожидающих проверки.

Понятно, почему:

1. для того, чтобы очередь сократилась на один «пункт», необходимо пять голосов рядовых участников (или одного модератора) за один из двух вариантов: «оставить открытым» или «закрыть (с той или иной формулировкой)».
2. за сутки рядовой участник может проголосовать в этой очереди лишь 20 раз.

---

Если не менять все эти глобальные настройки, то можно ли как-то по-другому ускорить процесс обработки этой очереди?

Comment: Я так понимаю, Вам пора "shift" на клавиатуре починить. :)

Comment: @alexolut Александр принципиально пишет без заглавных букв. Я это уже воспринимаю как авторский стиль. Discord, помнится, регулярно правил на заглавные. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, *регулярно правил* — может, раз пять-шесть и редактировал, но потом ему явно надоело.

Comment: @NickVolynkin следующая итерация - отказ от знаков препинания.

Comment: @alexolut, а потом и от пробелов :)

Comment: @Grundy, ага, а потом и от букв, с переходом на телепатию. спасибо за идею. ушёл разрабатывать миелофон.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

да, немного можно.

если очередной вопрос из очереди требует, с вашей точки зрения, закрытия, то, чтобы не «расходовать» дефицитный голос в этой очереди, можно проголосовать за закрытие вопроса, открыв его в новом окне/вкладке и нажав ссылку «закрыть» ниже текста вопроса. а в очереди проверок нажать для этого вопроса кнопку «пропустить».

---

недостатки:

1. если вы по каким-то причинам стараетесь никогда не закрывать вопросы, то описанный трюк бесполезен.
2. количество голосов за закрытие (хоть в очереди, кнопкой «закрыть», хоть вне очереди, ссылкой «закрыть» ниже вопроса) всё равно ограничено — не более 24<sup>1</sup> за сутки (счётчик оставшихся голосов отображается внизу диалога закрытия вопроса), и после исчерпания этого лимита голосование в очереди «за закрытие» станет недоступным до конца суток (utc).
3. если вы голосуете в этой очереди только с целью получения очередного «знака», то описанный трюк вам не поможет приблизить долгожданное вознаграждение.

---

<sup>1</sup> — теперь уже [не 24, а 50](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5174/178576)

Comment: *до конца суток (американских)* - по UTC

Comment: @Alex, да, точно, спасибо за напоминание.

Comment: Третий недостаток скорее можно записать в достоинство - если смотреть с другой стороны. )

Comment: @Alex скорее, английских.

Answer (score 8):

Ограничение нужно, чтобы мнение нескольких участников не задавало тон всему сайту. Несколько вопросов, на которые я отвечал, были закрыто слишком быстро и несправедливо (имхо).

Очередь обработается быстрее, если ею займутся больше участников. Но если вопрос — не спам, не халтура и не безумие, то мне, например, проще составить ответ или отстраниться, чем принимать решение о закрытии.

1. Я постоянно сомневаюсь, правильно ли я понял ситуацию и всё ли я о ней знаю. Чтобы разобраться как следует, нужно время, которого не хватает.
2. Закрытие — это крайняя мера. Меня надо заставлять ею воспользоваться.

Поэтому, чтобы проверять очередь на закрытие, мне (помимо 3000 баллов) пригодились бы личные комментарии от тех, кто голосовал за закрытие или против закрытия. Для этого не надо менять функционал сайта. Достаточно добавить комментарий к вопросу, но с объяснением от себя, а не стандартной формулировкой.

И будет круто увидеть, как кто-нибудь из проголосовавших за закрытие прочитал такие комментарии и передумал закрывать. Мне кажется, доверие к ресурсу складывается как раз из подобных ситуаций.

Comment: было бы неплохо отметить в тексте, что вы отвечаете не на исходный вопрос, а на [комментарий к одному из ответов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4154/4188#comment13974_4184).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо. Думал и про этот комментарий, и про вопрос в целом. Обновил ответ.

Comment: *или отстраниться, чем принимать решение о закрытии* — абсолютно неверный вариант, когда идёт речь об очереди «за закрытие». если ответы на вопрос, на ваш взгляд, могут быть полезны для базы знаний, которой является наш сайт, надо не «отстраниться», а проголосовать за «оставить вопрос открытым».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Когда могут быть полезны - да. А когда не знаю и нет времени разбираться?

Comment: как правило, для того, чтобы понять, могут ли быть полезными для базы знаний **ответы**, по-моему, достаточно всего лишь прочитать вопрос. если нет времени даже на чтение вопроса, тогда, конечно, не стоит «заходить» в очередь проверок «за закрытие» — будет сэкономлено время на многократные нажатия кнопки «пропустить».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вы передёргиваете ситуацию и поэтому спорите с тем, чего нет. Зашёл в очередь, читаю вопрос. Если спам, халтура или бред - закрыть. Если по делу - не закрывать. С теми вопросами, которые `достаточно прочитать`, проблемы нет. Проблема только в вопросах, за которые не уверен. Если есть время уточнить у автора и перепроверить себя - то скорее всего получится ответ на вопрос. Если есть комментарии от других участников, то они помогают проверить, правильно ли понял. Если доп. информации нет и не успеваю проверить сам - то за что голосовать?

Comment: я всего лишь комментировал ответ, данный на вопрос с заголовком «Как ускорить обработку очереди "за закрытие"?». прошу прощения за то, что мои комментарии больше относятся к теме вопроса, нежели к теме данного ответа.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле всё проще. [Каждый 6й, а то и каждый 4й, вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2782/178988) в очереди не получает ни единого голоса за закрытие. Усилия следует направлять не на разгребание очереди, а на то, чтобы в неё не попадали заведомо хорошие вопросы.

Comment: На самом деле, можно двигаться к уменьшению очереди с разных сторон, а не отдавать предпочтения какому-то одному подходу.

Answer (score 2):

Предложу вариант, однако, требующий некоторой замены "глобальных настроек".
Можно было бы разделить голоса за закрытие на 2 группы:

- Первичный голос за закрытие (оставить пороги как есть сейчас)
- Голос за поддержку первичного голоса (новый набор голосов)

Таким образом, кол-во раз, когда участник является инициатором закрытия вопроса остаётся прежним. Но если уже кто-то предложил закрытие, то голос за поддержку берётся уже из другого набора голосов. Ёмкость этого набора подлежит обсуждению.

Пока не очень складывается понимание того, чем это лучше простого увеличения кол-ва голосов за закрытие, но тем не менее решил мысль озвучить. Может у кого-то получится эту идею развить дальше.

Comment: «давайте вместе придумаем, зачем нам это изменение»

Comment: @alexanderbarakin мне вообще не очень понятно, зачем надо ограничивать возможности голосования по уже предложенному кем-то закрытию.

Comment: например, чтобы чьё-то мнение не стало доминирующим. я именно по этой причине долгое время не касался очереди «за закрытие», ведь у [меня там сейчас абсолютный «перевес»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats).

Answer (score 2):

Для участников, имеющих привилегию модерации (более 10к репутации), можно воспользоваться [соответствующими инструментами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last30days) и выбирать вопросы из списка «Голоса за закрытия». В таком случае голоса [очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/) (20 в сутки) не расходуются, а потребляются из другого набора (50 в день).