# тревога → не является ответом

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

что **именно** происходит при нажатии под ответом ссылки «тревога» и выборе пункта «не является ответом»?

судя по наличию рядышком пункта «требуется вмешательство модератора», явной передачи тревоги на рассмотрение модератором (при выборе пункта «не является ответом») не происходит.

возможно, ответ попадает в очередь проверок «сообщения низкого качества». а если этот ответ **уже** есть в этой очереди, то вообще ничего не происходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тревога попадает к модераторам в категорию «не является ответом».

Пункт «требуется вмешательство модератора» нужен для тревог с произвольным текстом жалобы в свободной форме.

Comment: спасибо, понятно. вопрос был задан в надежде как-то «ускорить» и обработку очереди «сообщения низкого качества», по типу [«уксорения» очереди «голоса за закрытие»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4155/178576).

Comment: А модераторы с ней что-то делают, или нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy варианты: преобразуют в комментарий, удаляют, улучшают, снимают флаг.

Comment: @Nofate, в смысле, вопрос же всё равно в очередь проверок отправится - можно же просто игнорировать? Т. е. по сути это очередь типа аналитики? Или всё же там реально какое-то действие от модератора нужно?