# как сделать 70 проверок в сутки в очереди «за закрытие»?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, очередь-проверок

в продолжение и развитие темы [Как ускорить обработку очереди «за закрытие»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4154/178576)

как известно, не так давно лимит голосов, которые можно «отдать» за *закрытие и повторное открытие*, [увеличился с 24 до 50](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5174/178576).

как этим можно воспользоваться во всё разрастающейся (в последнее время) очереди «[голоса за закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close)»?

Comment: Да хватит уже закрытие вопросов продвигать!

Comment: @Qwertiy, если я что-то и «продвигаю», так это **способ** быстрее «разгрести» очередь «голоса за закрытие». то, что очередь называется так кратко (а не «голоса за закрытие и за оставление вопросов открытыми, включая их правку») никак не подразумевает, что в ней можно только закрывать вопросы. и, кстати, я никогда никого не призывал ни «закрывать всё», ни «ничего не закрывать», ибо каждый вопрос требует отдельного рассмотрения.

Comment: Да, но предложенный способ предполагает 50 голосов за закрытие и 20 за оставить открытыми, т. е. больше 2/3 голосов направлены именно на закрытие ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, во-первых, как я специально и подчеркнул в ответе, сейчас длина очереди вполне достаточна, чтобы набрать и 50 вопросов, требующих закрытия. во-вторых, если уж додумывать какие-нибудь «предположения», то, учитывая текущую длину очереди (267), предположение 50/267 — ничем не хуже вашего 50/70.

Answer (score 5):

Hапример, в очереди «[голоса за закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close)» можно голосовать только кнопкой «оставить открытым» (или «править», при необходимости), а для вопросов, требующих, с вашей точки зрения, закрытия, нажимать кнопку «пропустить» (предварительно открыв сам вопрос в отдельной вкладке/окне и нажав там ссылку «закрыть» ниже текста вопроса).

Tаким образом, при наличии достаточного количества вопросов в очереди (а на данный момент их более чем достаточно — 265), за сутки можно осуществить до 70 проверок (20 — в очереди, и 50 — вне её).

**Hебольшая хитрость**: если количество проверок в очереди уже подходит к лимиту в 20 проверок, а лимит голосов за закрытие (50 в сутки) ещё не исчерпан, то можно начать пропускать и те вопросы, за которые вы бы хотели проголосовать «оставить открытым»: на следующий день вы можете вновь вернуться к этим проверкам и проголосовать за них. Для этого нажмите внизу [страницы истории проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/history) ссылку «[моя история проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/history?userId=0) — там в третьей колонке будут приведены ссылки непосредственно на проверки — отметьте внизу страницы «показать пропущенные проверки», и открывайте те ссылки, на которых написано «пропустить».

---

Hедостатки прежние:

1. Eсли вы по каким-то причинам стараетесь никогда не закрывать вопросы, то описанный трюк бесполезен.
2. Kоличество голосов за закрытие (хоть в очереди, кнопкой «закрыть», хоть вне очереди, ссылкой «закрыть» ниже вопроса) всё равно ограничено — не более 50 за сутки (счётчик оставшихся голосов отображается внизу диалога закрытия вопроса), и после исчерпания этого лимита голосование в очереди «за закрытие» станет недоступным до конца суток (utc).
3. Eсли вы голосуете в этой очереди только с целью получения очередного «знака», то описанный трюк вам не поможет приблизить долгожданное вознаграждение.

Comment: Всё это, конечно, замечательно. Но хотелось бы видеть это более юзер-френдли. А не чесать левое ухо пяткой правой ноги. В целом - плюсую.

Comment: @alexolut, ну, я описал «как использовать имеющиеся возможности, не претендуя на их расширение». или вы о том, что описание чересчур сложное?

Comment: ЭХ, счастливчик, всего лишь 265 отображается)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, у меня лично сейчас в этой очереди — 0 (прописью: ноль) вопросов, ожидающих проверки. а смотрел я от имени анонима (в данный момент показывает уже 258).

Comment: Я о том, что SO следует что-то менять в этом плане.