# Стоит ли ограничивать количество проверок до 20?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, очередь-проверок

Я сегодня проверил 20 сообщений низкого качества и 20 правок. Мог бы проверить и еще.
Зачем ограничивать количество?

Comment: Такая политика ресурса. Но Баракин например постил серию лайфхаков по небольшому увеличению, вот например https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5215/213987

Comment: @AK не слушайте Баракина, а то начнёте предложения с маленькой буквы писать :D

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Я обычно наоборот всем правлю на большую, хотел и тот ответ отредактировать, но поленился. Тогда уж поправлю.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica не советую трогать сообщения Александра :P

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Уже поменял, а что?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica  _**н**е слушайте Баракина_ - совет основан на личном опыте?)

Comment: @0xdb у меня с ним не было особо пересечений. Но в своё время была драма с правками его сообщений, насколько я помню)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Ну это я знаю. Я собственно почему не удержался спросить - "н" маленькая и в начале предложения.

Comment: @0xdb, там, скорее, пропущена запятая при использовании обращения (: