# Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?

Tags: обсуждение, faq, markdown, форматирование, стиль

***Это перевод***. Оригинал - [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right).

Недавно я сделал небольшой обзор вопросов, которые задают пользователи, и заметил, что большинство из них не пользуется внутристрочным выделением кода (например, «метод `main()`», или «класс `HelloWorld`») - другими словами, они не используют обратный апостроф (`).

Есть ли на SO страница или вопрос, на который можно отправить для объяснения, что такое выделение кода внутри строки и когда его стоит использовать (желательно с примерами)?

Я нашел вопрос [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right)  (Верно ли, что выделение кода внутри строки нежелательно использовать для смысловых ударений?). К нему есть хороший ответ, в котором говорится, что внутристрочное выделение следует использовать для «кода и кодообразных сущностей». Однако, тот вопрос приводит нас к другому вопросу - что такое «кодообразная сущность». Например, идентификаторы или фрагменты логов часто форматируют при помощи внутристрочного выделения, но их с трудом можно назвать «кодообразными сущностями». Можно привести и другие примеры, которые еще больше запутают дело.

Во многих изданиях по программированию имеется раздел, в котором приводится описание того, как и для чего в книге применяются то или иное форматирование текста. Есть ли на SO похожее описание относительно использования внутристрочного выделения кода?

Comment: Замечу, что на русском, использовать символ ` неудобно, т.к. он в английской раскладке.

Comment: @KromStern выделяете блок текста и Ctrl + K.

Comment: @NickVolynkin класс, спасибо!

Comment: Добавил этот вопрос в [Часто задаваемые вопросы о StackOverflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983)

Comment: @KromStern Проблем с апострофом у меня не возникло ни разу, поскольку код также в английской раскладке — всё равно переключаться.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko код часто копипастой вставляется

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Небольшое дополнение о случаях, когда есть гораздо лучшее решение, чем выделение для кода.

#### Элементы пользовательского интерфейса

Для элементов пользовательского интерфейса гораздо лучше подходит подходит html-тег `<kbd>...</kbd>`. Например:

> Для того, чтобы сохранить файл под новым именем, щелкните <kbd>Файл</kbd> > <kbd>Сохранить как...</kbd>, либо  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> ( <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  <kbd>S</kbd> )

#### Идентификаторы или фрагменты логов

> Довольно часто имеют строки очень большой длины и обычно предназначены для чтения человеком. Поэтому для них отлично подходит форматирование цитатой («`>`»  перед строкой).

Сравните с кодом:

`Довольно часто имеют строки очень большой длины и обычно предназначены для чтения человеком. Поэтому для них отлично подходит форматирование цитатой («>» перед строкой).`

```
Довольно часто имеют строки очень большой длины и обычно предназначены для чтения человеком. Поэтому для них отлично подходит форматирование цитатой («>» перед строкой).
```

#### Названия IDE, библиотек, плагинов, инструментов

Плохо:

> Для программирования под `Android` удобно использовать `Android Studio`.
>
> Использовал плагин `foobar` c гитхаба, ну который для друпала, только не форк (там баги) и не прошлая версия (она в другом месте), а который новый.

Хорошо:

Для широко известных инструментов (когда есть [метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) этого инструмента) — ничего. Их и так все знают.

При желании, вы можете использовать курсив (спасибо [pavlofff](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177345/pavlofff) за подсказку), *но только в своих сообщениях*. Курсив воспринимается как расстановка акцентов в тексте; добавлять курсив в чужие сообщения не стоит.

> Для программирования под андроид удобно использовать Android Studio.

Для менее известных (когда нет метки) – ссылка! Лучший способ выделить название библиотеки [foobar с гитхаба](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=foobar&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)  — дать ссылку точно на тот репозиторий, с которого вы ее взяли, указав также имя автора. Вот так:

> Использовал плагин [iwhitcomb/foobar](https://github.com/iwhitcomb/foobar).

#### Название языка, на котором у вас код в вопросе

Плохо:

> Написал вот такой вот код на языке `javascript`...

Хорошо: метка [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) на вопросе (не в тексте вопроса, а в специальном поле для меток).

#### Ссылки

Хорошо: [ссылка](http://example.com/someurl), [*ссылка*](http://example.com/someurl), [**ссылка**](http://example.com/someurl). Опять же, **в чужие сообщения не нужно добавлять курсив и полужирный шрифт**. Пусть автор сам решает, на что обращать внимание читателя.

Плохо: [`ссылка`](http://example.com/someurl), но нормально как код в ссылке: [ссылка на документацию по `printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: Подскажите `pavlofff` это обычная ссылка? или есть какие-нибудь отдельные способы для ссылок на профиле пользователей сайта?

Comment: В предыдущим комментарии (да и в этом тоже) я использовал `выделение кодом`  для `не кода`. Какие существуют правила хорошего тона при оформлении комментариев?

Comment: @4per 1) да, это обычная ссылка, сокращённого синтаксиса нет. 2) В основном всё то же самое, т.е. код или результат работы кода. Я ещё цитируемые сообщения выделяю так, но это личная инициатива.

Comment: Почему плохо выделять названия IDE, библиотек, плагинов, инструментов и мелких участков кода (таких как тип данных) - кодом? А не для этого ли придуман символ *«`»*, чтобы в тексте выделять мелкие внутристрочные блоки?

Comment: @DenisBubnov мелкие участки кода именно так и нужно выделять, внутристрочное форматирование кода придумано именно для них. Остальное — плохо, потому что появляется конфликт (несоответствие) формы и содержания. Это как синий с подчёркиванием шрифт, который не является ссылкой или как изображение кнопки, которое не является кнопкой. Как баннеры, которые с помощью оформления маскируются под основное содержимое сайта. Как кнопка «Скачать», которая открывает три рекламных страницы, а скачать не даёт. В общем, плохо и вызывает ненависть пользователей. ))

Comment: @DenisBubnov а конфликт появляется потому, что мы привыкли, что код на сайте выглядит совершенно определённым образом, а остальное выглядит иначе. И когда мы видим код, включается внутренний парсер/интерпретатор/компилятор. И сразу выдаёт ошибку: class Android Studio not found.

Answer (score 14):

Так как никто не привел никаких существующих соглашений об использовании внутристрочного выделения кода, я решил опубликовать собственное решение. Оно является моим личным мнением и обобщает мой опыт. Надеюсь, что оно окажется полезным.

**Для чего следует использовать внутристрочное выделение**

Любая строка, которая **обрабатывается** или **генерируется** компьютером, обычно должна быть выделена в тексте. На SO есть единственный способ это сделать (применить внутристрочное выделение кода) — поэтому я использую выделение для подсветки таких строк, когда пишу на SO. В документах для личного пользования, я делаю обычно только одно исключение — использую отдельный стиль оформления текста для выделения элементов пользовательского интерфейса (например, "`Файл` → `Открыть…`").

**Когда внутристрочное выделение использовать не стоит**

Строки, которые используются в документах, предназначенных для чтения человеком (например: торговые марки, названия пакетов программ, сами программы, библиотеки, технологии, аббревиатуры) — не выделяются как код, для них должен применяться другой стиль. Например HTTP, TCP/IP, HTML, CSS, AJAX, SQL, Linux, C++, .NET, SaaS, Spring Framework, LibreOffice, iPhone, jQuery, GUI.

**О строках, которые обрабатываются или генерируются компьютером**

- небольшие фрагменты листингов (например, `SELECT * FROM MyTable`, `this.id =id;`)
- имена классов, методов, блоков, переменных, параметров методов, строковые константы, имена файлов, пути к файлам, расширения файлов, теги HTML, предложения SQL, фрагменты конфигурационных файлов и тому подобное
- входные данные программ (например, значения, вводимые пользователем)
- вывод программ (фрагмент вывода на терминал, фрагмент лога)

**Двойственные случаи**

Имеются некоторые случаи двойственности: "gedit", — это имя популярного редактора текстов, а также команда, которая этот редактор запускает. Как имя программы, это слово НЕ СЛЕДУЕТ выделять, но как команду, интерпретируемую компьютером, следует. Возможно, форматирование следует выбирать в соответствии с контекстом употребления слова.

**О других соглашениях о форматировании**

В литературе по программированию часто содержится раздел, который объясняет, каким образом в книге используются те или иные стили текста. Эти соглашения являются более подробными, нежели те, что здесь приведены. Например, для пользовательского ввода и вывода программ могут использоваться отдельные стили. Однако, на SO нет таких возможностей оформления, чтобы удовлетворить такие широкие потребности. Кроме того, написание постов с использованием большого количества стилей, может оказаться трудоемким.

**Элементы пользовательского интерфейса**

Множество книг используют отдельный стиль текста для выделения таких элементов. Напрмер, "Выделите пункт `Сохранить Как…` в меню `Файл`." или Щелкните "`Файл` → `Сохранить как…`" Возможно, в случае SO, элементы интерфейса также стоит выделять при помощи внутристрочного выделения для кода.

**Использование кавычек**

Нет необходимости помещать фрагменты кода в дополнительные кавычки — они уже и так выделены. Однако, для строковых констант следует сделать исключение и приводить их вместе с разграничителями. Например: "Метод `sayHello()` возвращает `"Hello World!"`."

**Примеры**

**Java** (тексты примеров взяты из официальной документации http://docs.oracle.com/)

- Конвертация в строку осуществляется методом `toString`, который объявлен в `Object` и наследуется всеми классами Java.
- Если не указано иное, передача `null` в качестве аргумента конструктора или метода вызовет выбрасывание исключения `NullPointerException`.