# Использование курсива

Tags: обсуждение, правки, стиль

Есть ли какие-то общепринятые рекоммендации/гайды по использованию курсива?

Напрмер, в последнее время я виден несколько правок, которые сводятся исключительно к выделению курсивом технических терминов и названий языков: С++, Windows.

Пару таких правок я откатил, т.к. они, на мой взгляд, ухудшали читабельность, или акцентировали внимание не на тех словах, на которых его стоило акентировать.

Например, я не вижу смысла ставить *акцент* на C++ в случае, если на вопросе стоит тэг [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Примеры правок:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/472059/5
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/471952/2

Disclaimer: Я совсем не против того, что @Saidolim правит форматирование. Но хотелось бы определить какие-то общие рекомендации - чтобы исключить правки и откаты с обоснованием "мне так больше нравится".

Comment: Уместно, на мой взгляд, выделять имена собственные (напр. названия библиотек, программных продуктов), которых нет в тегах.

Comment: Для имен файлов как-то больше общеприняты `backticks`, а не *курсив*.

Comment: @Nofate: согласен, об этом есть тут в ответе gbg: [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1328)

Comment: вот Saidolim победит на выборах и тогда везде будет курсив )

Answer (score 11):

Я не знаю насчёт *общепринятого* мнения, моё личное мнение — выделение курсивом является смысловым акцентом, и должно восприниматься как часть авторского стиля. Поэтому мелкие правки такого рода кажутся мне излишними и даже возможно нарушающими замысел автора.

В качестве практически обязательных шрифтовых выделений мне видится лишь [выделение кода обратными апострофами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328).

Comment: Согласен. После правки в тексте как будто расставлены акценты, которых в исходном варианте не было. А ещё, когда я вижу *Windows*, мне кажется, что это должен быть какой-то особый Windows, не тот, что обычно.

Comment: Я считаю, что выделение курсивом имен инструментов, программ и проч. лучше сказывается на читаемости текста в целом. Я в своих сообщениях выделяю их курсивом.

Comment: @pavlofff: В своих — разумеется, вопрос здесь скорее о правках _чужих_ текстов.