# Косметические правки. "вы → Вы", "е → ё"

Tags: обсуждение, правила, стиль, ё

Довольно часто в очередь проверок правок попадают правки, исправляющие чистую косметику, причем довольно спорно исправляющие.

Я понимаю, что есть адепты использования буквы Ё, или люди считающие, что обращаясь к человеку на "вы", необходимо писать это слово с большой буквы. Но оба этих посыла достаточно спорны, и навязывать человеку свое видение на них как минимум не вежливо.

Что делать с такими правками, как кто считает?

Comment: Отклонять, как не вносящие существенных изменений.

Comment: Отклонить. Автора сжЁчь

Comment: насколько я помню такие правки считаются *незначительными* и не приветствуются

Comment: Предлагаю переформулировать вопрос, убрав "вы/Вы" и оставив "е/ё". На мете было достаточно вопросов про "вы/Вы": http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489/ и http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3318/

Comment: @AK вопрос не про интерфейс stackoverflow, а про посты пользователей

Comment: Ответ не пора принимать?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Использование «Е» или «Ё», а также обращение на «вы»/«Вы» — часть авторского стиля. Использование любого из них является нормативным как с точки зрения русского языка, так и с точки зрения сложившегося на ru.SO грамматического консенсуса.

Следовательно, такие правки являются излишними, незначительными, не улучшают вопрос/ответ, и, возможно, находятся на грани вредоносности. Мне кажется, автору правок следует мягко объяснить не просто ненужность, а и вред от его действий.

---

Связанные вопросы:

- [Использование курсива](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1958/10105)
- [Какое обращение следует использовать: Вы / вы / ты?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/489/)

Comment: Использование `выделения кодом` в правках тоже близко к этому вопросу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: За выделение кодом в чужих вопросах я бы очень мягко и толерантно расстреливал нахрен тупой пилой. Кто правит других, должен сначала сам прочитать справку. Дважды.

Comment: "Использование «Е» или «Ё», а также обращение на «вы»/«Вы» — часть авторского стиля. Использование любого из них является нормативным как с точки зрения русского языка" можете подкрепить ссылкой утверждение про нормативность любого из этих случаев?

Comment: @edem http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/51-rubric-88 `Окончательное решение о написании Вы с прописной (для подчеркивания этого уважительного отношения) принимает автор текста.` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%81#.D0.95_.D0.B8_.D0.81

Comment: @VladD килобаксов

Comment: @edem: А по по поводу Ё ещё [Миф № 7. Написание е вместо ё – грубая орфографическая ошибка](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_7_jo/). Хотя я сам последовательно использую «Ё» везде, я считаю себя не вправе навязывать это решение другим.

Comment: @rjhdby, VladD, спасибо, не знал, интересные ссылки.

Comment: @VladD а что не так, если кодом выделяется действительно код?

Comment: @alexolut: Если код, то всё в порядке (да и никто не заметит). Но к сожалению, очень часто выделяется всё, что угодно, кроме кода.

Comment: Правки с "вы/Вы" могут быть актуальны для тем на Мете, описывающих функционал сайта, т.к. по сути это можно считать продолжением справки. И в данном случае использование Вы/вы должно быть согласовано.

Comment: @alexolut: Да, согласен, это правильное исключение.

Answer (score 3):

Ё - тоже буква русского алфавита. Её ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО использовать! Почему? От беспечности авторов некоторых книг теряется смысл слов, в особенности "все" и "всё". 
Общепринято использовать букву ё, когда она обособляет значение слова.

Вы - лучше, конечно, писать с большой буквы, если говорится о великом человеке; и с маленькой, если речь идёт об объединении некоторых людей.

Мой ответ вкратце: если сильно меняет смысл, то нужно одобрять изменения.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45702/discussion-on-answer-by-egor-randomize------).