# Странное редактирование вопроса. Удаляются некоторые слова, которые я вообще не трогал

Tags: дефект, предлагаемые-правки, ревизии

При редактировании вопроса, уже в который раз натыкаюсь на мой взгляд странный дефект. Я выделяю некоторые слова, пример ниже, а он еще и текст удаляет(а иногда и нет) рядом с этим словом, хотя я всегда аккуратно все делаю и в этот раз не исключение. Вот скриншот:

> [image: сравнение редакций]

как видно в самом конце, почему-то удаляется "и отправить в".
Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?
[Ссылка на редакцию.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/667068/4)

Comment: ссылка на вопрос? ссылка на твою редакцию?

Comment: Обрати внимание на вопрос о том [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1338/186999)

Comment: может автор правил и смерждилось

Comment: но ведь конкретно в моей правке показывает, что это я удалил..

Comment: не удалил, а выделил обратными апострофами

Comment: Я наверное слепой) но мне кажется что "и отправить в" удалено. Разве нет?

Comment: Удалено. А Вы считаете, что не удалено? По другим словам: Вы добавили обрамление кодом через апострофы, т.к. между апострофом и словом пробелов нет - считается, что как будто было удалено всё слово без апострофов и добавлено такое же, но с апострафами. Это особенность диффа. Каких-либо дефектов тут не замечаю.

Comment: я считаю что удалено. точно так же как в этом случае я делаю остальные правки, но там ничего не удаляет

Comment: "создавать файл внутри Android" — тут `Android` должно быть внутристрочным кодом, только если это код или обрабатываемая кодом строка. Но не когда название ОС.

Comment: По дефекту: сотни раз редактировал, почти никогда ничего не терялось. Правда, однажды телефон в кармане разблокировался и я снёс половину огромного поста на Мете. Но это человеческий фактор уже. :)

Comment: у вас в комменте почти, с таким успехом и у меня почти) потому что это только второй раз, первый раз я свел это на свою ошибку, но когда второй раз уже такая штука появляется, я призадумался :)

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich да наверняка тоже случайно снесли пару слов )

Comment: Был ещё случай, когда в одном предложении, которое я не трогал, после моего редактирования слово "Было" изменилось на "Выло" и хз что к чему)

Answer (score 1):

За все свои на текущий момент 1167 правок на основном сайте я ни разу не наблюдал описанной ситуации. Возможно, либо Вы сами случайно выполнили удаление и не заметили этого, либо использованное Вами устройство ввода имеет какие-то особенности. Сказать однозначно трудно.

Чтобы можно было утверждать об ошибке конкретнее, я предлагаю Вам попробовать взять [ревизию сообщения до Вашей правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/fbe04989-5bb9-498a-b6ca-304a01d1e986/view-source) (сырой текст можно получить по ссылке "источник" в списке ревизий сообщения) и повторить те же действия в [специально предназначенном для проверки форматирования вопросе на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/339911). Если ситуацию удастся гарантированно повторить - шикарно, баг имеет место быть. Если нет - скорее всего текущий вопрос будет помечен меткой [статус-не-воспроизводится](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f) (когда модераторы вернутся с перекура).

Сейчас я не могу утверждать, что имеет место какая-то ошибка движка, со стороны это выглядит так, как будто Вы действительно удалили обсуждаемый участок текста, и продолжаете настаивать, что этого не делали. А наличие замен типа "Было"/"Выло", о которых Вы упомянули в комментариях, очень похоже на работу какого-то софта, выполняющего автозамену слов при вводе. Нечто подобное можно частенько наблюдать на мобильных устройствах. И если Вы для правки использовали нечто подобное - то ситуацию вполне можно было бы объяснить.

Comment: окей, спасибо, я попробую, но правил я с компа, поэтому вряд ли тут автозамена, описанное выше попробую обязательно.

Comment: Кстати, вопрос: почему песочница на MSE иногда получает статус protected (и поэтому постинг ответов для аккаунтов без репутации становится невозможным)? Это делается автоматически после наплыва спамботов, или какова причина такого поведения?

Comment: @Nikita что значит "иногда получает статус protected"? [Прежний Sandbox вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive) был недавно помечен как **locked** чтобы не плодить слишком уж много ответов в одном вопросе и назван как архив. Все эти пометки выставляются вручную насколько мне известно.

Comment: Ну.. нет, они просто перенесли посты в новый вопрос и его залочили, а вопрос остался прежним, только уже, понятно, без ответов. А вообще посмотрите [историю правок](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/revisions?page=1) вопроса, пролистайте пару страниц, там будут записи вида: Question Protected by Community♦, и затем записи о снятии этого статуса модераторами или пользователями, имеющими на это право.