# Защита от бесполезных и "пустых" вопросов

Tags: обсуждение

Добрый день уважаемое сообщество.

В последнее время по тем веткам, в которых я "обитаю" (`html/php/jquery/css/mysql`), укрепляется удручающая тенденция - поступают вопросы, как мне кажется, не характерные духу `stackoverflow`. Это когда постановка вопроса происходит по принципу **`"зачем мне что-то делать, если можно попросить сделать за меня"`** или **`вот картинка - хочу как на ней`**. Написать в `Мете` меня побудила шикарнийшая переписка в комментариях к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760675/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82), и вот [такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760560/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE-email) и [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760562/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC) с [таким](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/761517/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA) и ещё множество подобных вопросов.

Суть их очень проста. Многие пользователи данного ресурса, в основном новички в своих отраслях, не отягощают себя бременем поиска и ознакомления с учебными пособиями, офф. документацией, ну или хотя бы "методом тыка". В их понимании `stackoverflow` такое место, где делают за тебя, ибо **`"всё уже когда-то написано и реализовано, надо только найти и скопировать"`**. Такие специалисты получают минимально возможный объём знаний для начала монетизации своего труда. И отчаянно бросаются в продакшен. На выходе всегда одно и то же - грязный код, деревянная логика и прочие прелести шикакакода под красивой (и то не всегда) обёрткой. И, к сожалению, тут они часто получают помощь.

Никто не выигрывает от таких вопросов. Ни вопрошавший, сделавший своим вопросом шаг назад в своём же проф. развитии, ни отвечающий, потакающий подобной форме роста отраслевых бракоделов. Первые просто переполняют рынок рабочей силы, удешевляя средний чек. Вторые тратят совсем не лишнее время на поддержку первых на плову. Естественный отбор тут, если хотите, нарушен. Бракодел, ориентированный на финансовую прибыль, всегда опередит качественного и перспективного разработчика. Проверено временем помноженным на мой скромный опыт.

Я вижу, конечно, что сообщество бдит, работают проверки вопросов и ответов. Но часто некачественные вопросы (и ответы) ускользают от бдительного контроля неравнодушных участников. И копится и пополняется база знаний `stackoverflow` тем, чем ей пополняться и копится не надо. И от того куча вопросов, у которых по 20 просмотров за месяц, куча комментариев ни о чём - и ни одного ответа.*

А как вам такое - зарегистрироваться, задать вопрос и не получив ответ или, того хуже, получив разгром в комментариях за лень/глупость/и т.д. - зарегистрироваться новым пользователем и опять задавать вопрос. Есть ли необходимость в таких акаунтах, в таких вопросах?

Я и сам постоянно пользуюсь `stackoverflow` в работе, за что отдельная благодарность. В основном англоязычным, и вот что я подметил - там вопросов по типу **`ребятки, а забацайте-ка мне вот эдакое, а то я что-то хз как оно работает`** не встречается. А у нас довольно много. Почему?

Как быть? Может это и не проблема вовсе и всё "`идёт по плану`"? А может стоит всё же это как-то решать? Например, верификация акаунта через аттестацию по правилам формирования контента на `stackoverflow`. Это ведь не трудно, дать понять пользователю что, например, найти плагин или установить тему - это к гуглу.

Считаю за честь быть частью сообщества. Благодарю за внимание.

*На основании общего впечатления, цифры не конкретные.

Comment: Общество у нас такое, больше не скажу, ибо коммент опять удалят за нецензурщину или сарказм. А еще проблемы образования, воспитания и самодисциплины. В общем, "не мы такие, время такое" (с)

Comment: И что вы предлагаете? Закрыть SO за то, что он - гнездо бракоделов? Может неочевидно - но ситуация "кто-то делает чужую работу и получает за это медальки" - это и есть суть SO )

Comment: @PashaPash Вы не верно трактуете мой пост. Мне интересно мнение сообщества по данному вопросу, т.к. я увидел в этом определённую "засоренность" ресурса.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin я трактую ваш пост так, как могу (или как хочу). Суть любого ответа на SO - "кто-то принес часть своей работы на stack overflow". Учебные задания, за выполнение которых автор не получит денег, встречаются, но их почему-то активно пытаются запретить. Так что можно смело считать, что ответив на любой вопрос, вы сделаете за кого-то часть его работы. Он получит за это деньги, а вы - ничего. Особенно в вашем стеке - нет в html/php/jquery/css/mysql ничего такого, чего нельзя было бы решить самостоятельно - гуглением, самообучением и тыком.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin поэтому любой вопрос по html/php/jquery/css/mysql можно прямо считать попыткой свалить на кого-то свою работу, и срубить по-быстрому денег, вместо того, чтобы решить проблему самостоятельно, пользуясь поиском, документацией и отладчиком.

Comment: @PashaPash вы с чем работаете преимущественно? Каков ваш профилирующей инструментарий?

Comment: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2017/12/08/stack-overflow-patchwork/

Comment: Если вернуться к вопросу - то да, проблема (ну или по крайней мере, явление) есть. Но вы не приводите криериев оценки "плохих" вопросов. И критерии аттестации сомнительны. Вы же сами задавали вопрос "как поставить плагин" - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624704/ - представьте, что за такой вопрос вас бы забанили и вообще сюда не пустили (читай мануал! к гуглу!)

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ и за интерес, проявленный к моему вопросу. А критерии аттестации - лишь размышления на тему, не больше. Не беру на себя ответственность предлагать конкретные рецепты, по крайней мере на данном этапе своего развития. Касательно плохих вопросов - это подобные тем, ссылки на которые я давал в первом абзаце.

Comment: @svgrafov спасибо, отредактирую.

Comment: @alexolut благодарю за внимательность. к сожалению, я не был до сих пор знаком с постом по этой ссылке.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin всё украдено до нас (ц)

Comment: @alexolut прекрасный фильм! =)

Comment: @jfs да, старшие товарищи уже указывали на данное обстоятельство, только со ссылкой на другой пост. Я убедился, что вопрос неоднократно поднимался.

Comment: "Но часто некачественные вопросы (и ответы) ускользают от бдительного контроля неравнодушных участников" - Тревог и минусов накидайте, и все. А старые вопросы без заплюсованных ответов дух потрет.

Answer (score 12):

Вы видите последствия, но, на мой взгляд, не совсем верно понимаете причины и саму суть явления "ленивых новичков".

Вы видите в вопросах от новичков *осознанное* нежелание разбираться и попытки "обогащения за счет добрых людей-экспертов". На самом деле никакого осознания нет.

*Любой* человек в процессе обучения *любому* навыку проходит 4 стадии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот определение новичка в этой модели (болд - мой):

> Новичок (Begginer)
>
> На этом уровне находятся люди, которые не знают о существовании или **не осознают важность определенных знаний**. Иногда даже **отвергающие важность и полезность этих знаний**.
>
> Пока новичок не осознает нехватку знаний/навыков, невозможно стать лучше и перейти на следующий уровень. Осознание приходит при общении с более опытными коллегами или при столкновении с проблемами/задачами, которые невозможно или очень трудно решить, обладая текущим набором знаний/умений. **Попытки научить чему-либо новичка, обычно, ни к чему не приводят, пока он сам не перейдет на следующий уровень**.

Это проявляется в любой области, от вождения машины и кодинга на PHP до строительства ракет. И никакая "жёсткость к новичкам" тут не поможет. Проявлять жесткость к новичкам - это как подрезать и оттормаживаться перед машиной с буквой У на крыше.

Это нельзя "починить". Никак. Это не поломка, не баг, не лень, не попытка срубить по-легкому денег и не злой умысел. Просто люди так вот учатся *всему*. Смиритесь и помогите новичкам перейти в ученики.

---

P.S. Если посмотреть на ситуацию с другой стороны - то вы сейчас находитесь на стадии новичка *в области построения сообществ*. Опытные участники на сайте - ближе к практикантам и экспертам. И поэтому им так тяжело донести до вас (и до остальных новичков) правильные подходы в модерировании/отношении к "новичкам в php" - вы просто не осознаете суть проблемы и пытаетесь решить ее дешево и сердито - "что-нибудь запретить". Одна из целей меты - помочь "новичкам" в построении сообщества стать хотя бы "учениками".

Comment: Спасибо, пища для размышлений безусловно есть. Однако вы напрасно принимаете мой пост в штыки. Цель его исследовательская, мне действительно интересно ваше(сообщества) мнение по данному вопросу. Никаких революций =)

Answer (score 5):

На двух стульях не усидишь. А именно это почему-то пытаются сделать многие топовые пользователи ru SO - пытаются и к новичкам быть снисходительными, и закрывать "плохие" вопросы.

Я сейчас не буду конкретизировать, что значит "плохой" вопрос. Речь не о том. Почему-то многие считают, что если не сюсюкаться с новыми пользователями, то они уйдут. Да боже мой, пускай уходят. Если человек зарегистрировался только, чтоб задать свой вопрос, но обиделся и ушёл, то скатертью дорога.

Другое мнение, я уже слышал его не раз - "SO - это база знаний. Вы помогаете не топикстартеру, а всем тем, кто придёт сюда из поисковиков". Да, помогаем точно таким же бракоделам...

Это я к чему:

1. Нужно с новичками быть жёстче.
2. Нещадно закрывать такие вопросы, что я и стараюсь делать.

Comment: благодарю ваше за мнение.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin а теперь применим это мнение в вашему вопросу. на мете: что, тяжело воспользоваться поиском и дать ссылки на смежные вопросы? лень было нормально оформить текст? почему не ознакомились с правилами форматирования, перед тем постить на мету и повыделяли как код то, что кодом не является? в конце концов - как можно было проигнорировать такое базовое правило, как "не приветствовать и не прощаться в постах???

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, я понял Ваше мнение и обязательно приму его во внимание.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin научитесь пользоваться поиском, хотя бы с правилами оформления вопросов, почитайте https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/ и https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/616/, сформулируйте конкретные предложения и только потом задавайте вопросы на мете

Comment: @KirillKorushkin на самом деле нет, просто это прямое проявление предлагаемого "с новичками быть жёстче" от кого-то, у кого больше медалек, чем у вас. Не надо быть жёстче. Надо быть дружелюбнее - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice :)

Comment: @PashaPash буду настаивать на том, что мы всё же не про Новичков (мне самому ещё многому учиться), но про Лентяев.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin с новичками тоже не стоит сюсюкаться. Если вы один раз гостю разрешите в ботинках по квартире ходить и следы оставлять, он так и будет потом делать постоянно.

Comment: И вообще ни с кем не стоит сюсюкаться. Сразу банить :)

Comment: @PashaPash зачем утрировать =/ Новичкам надо дать понять, что есть определённые правила на нашем ресурсе.

Comment: ...и эти правила касаются всех,  а не только новичков. Жестче можно быть только в рамках be nice. Участник с высокой репутацией,  нарушающий be nice, тем более по отношению к новичкам, наносит гораздо больший вред, чем десяток лентяев. SO существует для получения ответов на вопросы. Вопросы задают в основном новички. Если быть к ним жесткими (жестче,  чем к опытным участникам) - вопросов станет меньше, и хороших,  и плохих.

Answer (score 5):

Как мне кажется, мир не может быть бинарным, где есть что–то строго хорошее и строго плохое. Обычно, мы существуем где–то посередине с небольшими отклонениями в сторону «плохого» или «хорошего». Мы уже видели, что в общем случае, [вопросы от новичков крайне полезны](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4882/6), а [задать вопрос на сайте много сложнее, чем найти ответ через поиск](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/). С другой стороны, всегда найдутся те, кто будет пытаться воспользоваться помощью сообщества, «когда надо и не надо». Отличить «хорошего» изучающего, который через год сам будет помогать сообществу, от «хитреца» крайне сложно.

В реальном мире невозможно руководствоваться догадками, о целях автора вопроса на сайте, его окладе, сообразительности, сложности вопроса для автора и т.д. В большинстве случаев мы ошибемся. Как минимум, далеко не все люди нашей профессии могут качественно развернуто объяснить то, чего они хотят, а попав в незнакомую социальную ситуацию (например, уточняющие комментарии от «авторитетных участников» с большой репутацией), люди могут вести себя крайне неоднозначно. От этого они ни как технические специалисты, ни как люди в общем не становятся хуже.

На мой взгляд, в подобных ситуациях следует руководствоваться миссией проекта и вашими жизненными целями. Миссия проекта — собрать свободную базу знаний по всем прикладным вопросам о программировании. Если сообщение содержит вопрос, удовлетворяет стандартам качества, соответствует тематике сообщества, может получить однозначно верный ответ и еще не было опубликовано ранее, его стоит оставить на сайте, вне зависимости получит автор вопроса за это оплату как за свой труд или нет.

Подчеркну, мы все используем чьи–то знания и чью–то работу каждый день и получаем за это оплату труда: языки программирования, компиляторы, книги, ответы со Stack Overflow — все это кто–то создал для нас, и большенство из этого досталась нам бесплатно. Единственное отличие — разная доступность (порог вхождения). Поэтому нам иногда кажется, что что–то есть результат нашего труда, когда нам пришлось приложить чуть больше усилий, чем обычно, чтобы освоить инструмент или найти знания, хотя, по факту, все, что у нас есть, кто–то сделал за нас, для нас, для сообщества.

Далее [выбор остается за вами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-friendly): либо вы можете и хотите помочь сообществу в создании базы знаний, либо — нет.

Comment: благодарю за вашу точку зрения.

Answer (score 1):

> В последнее время по тем веткам, в которых я "обитаю" (html/php/jquery/css/mysql), укрепляется удручающая тенденция - поступают вопросы, как мне кажется, не характерные духу stackoverflow. Это когда постановка вопроса происходит по принципу "зачем мне что-то делать, если можно попросить сделать за меня" или вот картинка - хочу как на ней.

Такое происходит везде и давно уже. И на форумах, и на "большом" SO (как там обычно английский SO называют, я не знаю). Везде, где можно спросить, приходят двоечники и "спрашивают" готовое решение. Каждый борется как может. Знаю один форум, там ввели правило, требующее обязательно привести собственные попытки решения (причем нормальные попытки, не отписки), а если их нет - модератор блокирует возможность отвечать. У ТСа остается возможность исправить пост, после исправления топик разблокируется. В принципе, на SO необходимый функционал для этого уже есть, достаточно только добавить новую причину для закрытия, например, "очевидно учебная задача без попыток самостоятельного нешения". Ну и чтобы особо не лютовать, принять за правило "любое сомнение [в том, что задача учебная] трактуется в пользу спрашивающего".

Comment: Такая причина есть уже довольно давно. Но [происходили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6189/176217) с ней и некоторые метаморфозы.

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо за мнение. Это интересно.

Comment: @alexolut Черт, действительно есть. Я даже видел пару недель назад, когда понадобилось нажать кнопочку "тревога". Забыл просто. Тогда, получается, не такая уж и большая проблема.