# Причина отката изменения к изначальной авторской

Tags: обсуждение

[Редакция 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/763522/revisions)

Хотелось бы узнать, что в моей правке было неправильного.

Comment: @pashapash, прокомментируйте, пожалуйста

Comment: Ответ [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/176217)

Comment: Хотел написать в личку - не успел. Да, там внутристрочное выделение кода используется слишком активно, причем, в основном, не для кода.

Comment: @PashaPash а зачем в личку, если вопрос публично задан и может быть полезен для других своим напоминанием как форматировать сообщение?

Comment: @alexolut в личку - сразу после отката правки, а не вместо ответа на мете :)

Comment: @PashaPash надо иметь поле ввода для лички сразу при откате правки значит. И одной кнопкой всё делать.

Comment: Понял, лучше метками заменять, если возможно. @PashaPash, а насколько в вопросе обращение `Всем привет, уважаемые знатоки.` соответствует правилам?

Comment: @gil9red Оно "не соответствует правилам оформления" , т.к. [у нас принято вырезать приветствия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/). Но при этом приветствие не является "нарушением правил, за которое пользователя стоит наказать". Лично я не стал бы править достаточно хорошо оформленное сообщение исключительно ради удаления "привет".

Comment: @PashaPash ну и зря!

Comment: @alexolut не вижу, чтобы кто-то из ненавистников приветствий спешил вырезать его из вопроса, правку которого мы тут обсуждаем :)

Comment: @PashaPash, потому что думают, раз модератор оставил, значит так и нужно :)