# Лишение репутации через правки. Что делать?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, предлагаемые-правки, правки, отклонённые-правки

Что делать, если некоторые участники с репутацией более 3000 присуждают себе предложенные мной правки? Видел такое уже много раз. И теперь даже нашёл одного такого виновника. Могу предоставить ссылку для разбирательства.

Ранее мне было непонятно куда исчезают мои правки.

---

**Добавлено более 1,5 часа спустя:**
Невнимательная проверка крадёт мои время, силы и возможности, даже если за саму правку не получает повышения своей репутации (как мне уже написали). Я мог бы их потратить на что-то полезное.

---

**Добавлено более 3 часа спустя:**
Поскольку уже и так личность проверяющего всплыла в нижеследующем обсуждении, то предоставляю здесь также и [ссылку на предложенную мной правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/262082).

Comment: Вам помочь с поиском и добавлением ссылки?

Comment: @0xdb, я думаю чтобы не позорить участника в открытую предоставить ссылку модераторам лично. Или как сделать лучше?

Comment: Если есть сомнения - оставьте на подправленном вопросе или ответе тревогу для модератора

Comment: Но вообще "пользователям с 3к" нет никакого смысла "красть правки" - они не получают за них репутации :)

Comment: @PashaPash, хорошая мысль! Пожалуюсь так.

Comment: На всякий случай - если вы про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/262044 - то правку отклонили потому, что тут не принято дописывать [решение найдено] в заголовок. Вместо этого используются отметки на ответах.

Comment: @PashaPash, нет, там не эта правка. А что касается именно той правки, то там ответов нет - ответ дан в отзыве к вопросу.

Comment: Может эта правка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/830110/revisions. Но там вашу правку приняли.

Comment: @0xdb, нет, там не эта правка. В той правке я теперь не указан наверное. Но не важно - я сейчас пожалуюсь через "тревогу" и модераторы разберутся.

Comment: @PashaPash, оставил на подправленном вопросе тревогу для модератора.

Comment: Видимо, я имеюсь в виду, поскольку отклонял правки участника. Bharata, // **1** Посмотреть судьбу Ваших правок Вы можете, зайдя в профиль → `Все действия` → `Предложения`. [**Пример**](https://i.imgur.com/wLQp4N7.png). К сожалению, уведомления, что правка отклонена, пользователю не приходят, на это обращал внимание. // **2** Каждую отклонённую правку ([**как и приведённую выше**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/262044)) я стараюсь аргументировать, не пользуясь ужасными шаблонными причинами отклонения.

Comment: // **3.** Если Вы не согласны с аргументацией, лучше сначала [**написать участнику, отклонившему Вашу правку**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/199934), обоснуйте свою позицию. // **4.** Если консенсуса/договорённости достичь не удастся, оспаривайте решение здесь, на Мете. Спасибо.

Comment: "В той правке я теперь не указан наверное" - ну почему же? Дополню @СашаЧерных: все, а не только Вы, могут видеть все Ваши [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/297453/bharata?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: @СашаЧерных вы отклоняете правки, и после этого повторяете их, с небольшими изменениями. Например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/262082 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/830122/revisions. Не стоит так делать. "Отклонить и править" - для случая "отменить предложенные изменения и внести свои".

Comment: По пунктам. // **1.** [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/262082) отклонил правку, потому что Вы исправили на неверное название. [Правильное название](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/commercial/) сервиса — `Яндекс.Карты`. У Яндекса названия всех сервисов пишутся с точкой после слова `Яндекс`. // 2. Почему отклонил [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/262044), написал в аргументации к отклонению. // Больше Ваших правок не отклонял. Спасибо.

Comment: @PashaPash, по `Яндекс.Картам` только что отписался. `вы отклоняете правки, и после этого повторяете их` — если ещё есть какие-то замечания по данному поводу, пожалуйста, диффы. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных по диффам - на сайте поломан таймлайн, и тяжело понять, были ли в отклоненной правке какие-либо изменения кроме названия сервиса. В отклоненной правке уже исправлен капс букв, добавлено выделение кодом и прочее. Эти же изменения отображаются в диффе вашей правки. Их внесли вы? или Bharata?

Comment: @PashaPash, если бы я не начал править то сообщение, его бы никто не начал править. Поощрения в виде 2 очков к репутации видимо для этого и придумали. А получается, что я вообще не при делах. Это очень неприятно.

Comment: @PashaPash, // **1.** если поломан таймлайн, и доказать проблематично, почему Вы произносите фразу `вы отклоняете правки, и после этого повторяете их, с небольшими изменениями` в утвердительной, а не вопросительной или условной («возможно») форме? // **2.** Помню, что запятые, `Яндекс`, `Яндекс.Карты`, `geocode` делал я. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных тогда не вижу проблем - достаточно было написать топпикастеру, что именно пошло не так с правкой, а не предлагать ему "написать участнику, отклонившему правку" со ссылкой на пост, в котором сказано, что лично участнику написать нельзя :)

Comment: @Bharata правки, предлагаемые участниками до 2000, попадают на проверку минимум двумя другими участниками. Поэтому такие правки должны, по возможности, исправлять все недочеты в сообщении - иначе проверяющие с большой вероятностью из завернут.

Comment: @PashaPash, думаю, что нам не стоит более уделять наше время и силы этим разбирательствам. Не стоят эти запятые наших сил, хотя и указать на это было надо. Думаю, что все подумали об этом достаточно и впредь будут об этом знать и учитывать это.

Comment: @Bharata, Забейте. Попался Вам излишне дотошный проверяющий, что теперь? Лучше ответить, получить голос и это покроет 5 правок!

Comment: @AK, новый пользователь, совсем не влился в жизнь сообщества

Comment: @Arthur, Я даже знать не хочу в каком сообществе **до** нашего принято так сплеча судить и разбрасываться такими эпитетами.

Comment: @Other, почему человек сделал такие выводы? Что можно украсть? Полагаю не время уж точно=) Правки - улучшение качества Q-A, а значит и самого сообщества. Может вообще не стоит поощрять репутацией за правки? Она же не должна давать стимул для этого.

Comment: @Arthur, [Нельзя время украсть, говорите...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmyF-XTrHeU)

Comment: @AK, я исправил сообщение в соответствии в вашими замечаниями.

Comment: @Other, да ну, это беспредел(по поводу видео), но тот промежуток времени, который проходит во время редакции Q-A, совсем мизерный, а если посчитать, сколько мы тратим времени  в день на мелочи, так вообще..

Comment: @СашаЧерных, зайдите пожалуйста в чат. Я там [вам сообщние оставил](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44954147#44954147).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Что делать?

В первую очередь постараться справиться со своими негативными эмоциями (гнев, обида и т.п.). Вполне возможно, что проверяющие (а это всегда не один конкретный человек: во избежание персональных ошибок решения принимаются не единоличным образом, а коллегиально) действовали из благих побуждений. И если вы начнёте разбираться в состоянии аффекта, то это приведёт только к негативным последствиям.

Могу привести такой пример. Не все новички знают правила сайта, их довольно много и сходу нельзя узнать все. Одна из типовых ошибок — это злоупотребление [внутристрочным форматированием](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/213987). Оно почему-то часто нравится новичкам и они его часто применяют в правках, "раскрашивая" "недостающую" разметку. А её потом отклоняют. Это не проверяющие злые, просто такие правила использования. Я в подобных случаях всегда даю ссылку на тему на мете, чтобы можно было прочитать и разобраться.

Во-вторых, вы можете связаться с каждым из рецензентов. Поскольку [механизма личных сообщений на сайте нет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/213987) — просто оставьте сообщение под одним из ответов. Правила хорошего тона подразумевают, что после того, как получен ответ "пинг" удаляется. (Переписка по правке логичнее выглядит под не/исправленным ответом)

В-третьих, вы можете пройти в [основной чат сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) и получить там поддержку. Как правило, там всегда находится кто-либо онлайн из ветеранов сайта, кто разбирается в правилах и обычаях сообщества и может подсказать, есть ли признаки вандализма в правках и на что вообще похоже.

В-четвёртых, вы можете пройти на мету; обратиться к модераторам или управляющему сообществом через форму обратной связи. Я, как сторонник демократии и местного самоуправления считаю, что лучше не дёргать по пустякам модераторов и КМ, он вообще у нас один — а послушать советы бывалых пользователей: сегодня расскажут вам, а завтра вы уже будете рассказывать кому-то, выступая в роли знатока и старожила.

Также, помимо этих четырёх советов я бы хотел обратить внимание на конкретику этих правок. Далее — моё личное мнение, я как проверяющий в очередях стараюсь придерживаться этого подхода, но не могу гарантировать, что подобный подход будет и у других участников.

Когда проверяющий не полностью согласен с предложенной правкой  у него всегда есть выбор следующего характера: он может либо нажать кнопку "улучшить правку" и внести дополнительные корректировки в ваши предложения, либо нажать "отклонить и править" и внести дополнительные правки но уже на базе исходного текста.

Допустим, вы внесли правку, которая содержит исправления форматирование кода и добавили внутристрочное форматирование. Если я лично не согласен с тем, что в данном случае необходимо внутристрочное форматирование, но согласен что формат кода нужен и полезен — то я могу либо "улучшить правку" (из вашей правки вырезать внутристрочное), либо "отклонить и править": мне покажут в редакторе исходный текст и я повторю форматирование кода)

С одной стороны этот механизм служит тому, чтобы было проще редактировать (иногда удобнее из крупной правки откатить лишь одну её часть, иногда напротив крупная правка почти целиком ошибочна, но в ней есть нечто хорошее, что проще воспроизвести заново).

С другой стороны, этот механизм может использоваться для того, чтобы указать автору правок на существенную ошибку. Так, для меня лично некорректное использование внутристрочного форматирования — это грубая ошибка, которая достойна того, чтобы я отклонил правку, лишив вас премии за правку. Мне это не очень удобно, приходится ещё искать тему, связываться с автором и прилагать кучу усилий — но если уж взялся проверять очередь, то халтурить не стоит.

Если бы мне *лично мне* попалась правка с яндекс картами (я сам, оказывается тоже неправильно пишу: яндекс:карты, яндекс:метрика) я бы воспользовался механизмом принять-но-улучшить, так как на мой личный взгляд это не тот вид ошибок, который достоин лишения премии за правки. Хотя люди разные бывают, проверяющие тоже разные — и в рамках допустимых правил у нас достаточно свободы действовать индивидуальным образом. Я, к слову, часто сталкивался на кодревью с суровыми проверяющими, которые не прощали мне ни малейшую небрежность — и я благодарен этим людям, которые двигали меня к более совершенному коду.

Что до наказания плохих проверяющих. Если кто-то часто ошибается в очередях проверок — то система автоматически на некоторое время отстраняет его от участия в проверках. Я сходу могу вспомнить только один случай, когда жалобы на правки пришлось рассматривать всем сообществом на мете, чтобы показать, что проверки вандальные и участника нужно временно отстранить — а обратное происходит гораздо чаще. Почти каждый месяц-два кто-нибудь в чате жалуется на слишком строгую систему, которая отстранила его от проверок. И от такого не застрахованы даже старички, которые много и часто проводят времени в очередях проверок.

Comment: (Наверное не буду добавлять в ответ, что обе кнопки "принять/отклонить-и-править" ведут к единоличным решениям и их всё же стоит избегать по-возможности)

Comment: Благо дарю вам за столь развёрнутый, старательный ответ и за ваши время, силы и старания! Очень приятно! Я за него проголосовал, но перепомечать его как верным не буду, т.к. это было бы несправедливым к участнику, кототрый своевременно предложил мне в ответе "поставьте тревогу". Надеюсь вы не будете за это на меня в обиде?! ;-)

Comment: Внутристрочным форматированием я не пользуюсь в правках и считаю, что они не стоят того, чтобы делать правку. А вот тот проверяющий к моей правке добавил именно внутристрочное форматирование К ОДНОМУ ЛИШЬ СЛОВУ.

Answer (score 4):

Как именно происходит "кража"?
Правда это довольно громкое заявление, ведь кража определяется как "тайное хищение чужого имущества".
Правка ничего не крадёт, Ваши усилия тоже принадлежат сообществу.

Впрочем да, некрасиво это, поставьте тревогу под "украденным" сообщением, обратитесь в чате к модераторам, но, честно говоря, вряд ли чем-то можно помочь, ведь формально "воришка" делает всё по закону.

Comment: Воришка крадёт мои время, силы и возможности, даже если за саму правку не получает повышения своей репутации (как мне уже написали).

Comment: Создавая (и модифицируя) контента на SO, Вы отдаёте его сообществу. Т. е. Вы должны понимать что правку может кто-угодно поменять и это будет в рамках лицензии. Не хотите тратить время/силы или хотите, но чтобы была возможность кого-то за это засудить - создавайте контент под проприетарной лицензией. Правда не на SO.

Comment: @Other _"кража определяется как ..."_ - юрист-наци детектед? При чем тут это?

Comment: @user6698332, При том, что это подходит. Я, конечно, не юрист, но это элементарное определение.

Comment: @Other Ну... просто смещает тональность твоего ответа в неуместно-ироническую сторону :( Я, прекрасно зная - что есть кража, в контексте темы подразумевал, что речь идет о присвоении чужого, а не о том, каким образом это сделано, о хищении в обывательском, а не специализированном смысле слова... пока не наткнулся на твое замечание.

Comment: @user6698332, 1) Я хотел указать на неуместное слово. 2) Не вижу проблем с смещением смыслов :)