# Во вкладке `Метки/Новые` неправильный род слова `Создано`

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

Во вкладке [Метки/Новые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) неправильный род слова `Создано`, слово `метка` - женского рода, значит должно быть `Создана`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рекомендую создавать сразу прямые ссылки на обсуждаемые вкладки, это упростит проверку. Ещё прошу обратить внимание на подход [использования встроенного кода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/176217) на сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подправил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14202). Предположительно это именно он. Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.8.10.43574